# Shopping list for surviving summer

Tags: dont-starve, reign-of-giants

I'm worried that I won't be able to survive my first summer in Reign of Giants. So I am thinking about what I will need. I guess it's normal to not be able to move out of camp very much because of the heat, so stocking up on stuff is crucial. I also realised that twigs wither, so there won't be lots of those around. Also I have not managed to get even one of my farms to produce anything. I guess I should count them out for the summer. So I am looking for tips for what needs to be in stock before first summer starts. For example:

- Endothermic Firepit
- Ice Box
- X Grass
- X Twigs
- X Fertilizers/Rot/Manure
- X Logs
- Ice Cube

I know there is probably not a perfect list out there, but I'd like to have the more experienced player's view on this.